# VBA alert when the result is different by 0

Tags: ms-access, vba, msgbox

I have this code:

```
DM.OnUpdate="CalculDiferenta"
DM.OnInsert="CalculDiferenta"

Sub CalculDiferenta

If Dsrid.Value=50000 Then

stl.first
Do While Not Stl.Eof
Diferenta.Value=Cantv.Value-Cantc.Value


Stl.Next
Loop

end if
End Sub
```

It calculates the difference between 2 Quantity columns in a document. 
Now, i want to be alerted if there is any difference (Cantv.Value-Cantc.Value <> 0 ). The code should check every line of the document for any differences and when it finds the first one, stop and show msgbox.

I did this, but i'm not sure it's ok. It show's a pop up just when the last line has a difference.

```
DM.OnUpdate="VerificareDiferente"
DM.OnInsert="VerificareDiferente"

Public Sub VerificareDiferente

If Dsrid.value=50000 and Cantv.Value-Cantc.Value <> 0  then

stl.first
             Do  While Not Stl.Eof
       MsgBox "Exista diferente intre cantitate comandata si cantitate verificata.", vbInformation, "Atentie !!!"
             Stl.Next
             Loop
       end if
End Sub
```

Could you help me guys ? Thank you.

Comment: consider editing your code blocks for clarity. I suspect that there is an error with the order of the if and while statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just misplaced your `If` statement, it should be inside the loop :

```
DM.OnUpdate = "VerificareDiferente"
DM.OnInsert = "VerificareDiferente"

Public Sub VerificareDiferente()
    Stl.first
    Do While Not Stl.EOF
        If Dsrid.Value = 50000 And Cantv.Value - Cantc.Value <> 0 Then
            MsgBox "Exista diferente intre cantitate comandata si cantitate verificata.", _
                vbInformation, "Atentie !!!"
        Else
        End If
        Stl.Next
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Great, that was the problem :D

Comment: May i have another question ?

It pop's up a msgbox for every line where are differences. How can i pop up just one msgbox even if i have 1 line with differences or "n" lines ?

Comment: @IonutP. Add a counter inside the loop (`i = i +1` or smthg like that) and put the `MsgBox` after the loop with a test like `If i > 0 Then MsgBox` ;)